# Multiple array grouping - ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs

I get my `data` like below;

```
[
  {
    // restaurant details here,
    "restaurant_class": {},
    "city": {},
    "location": {},
    "menu_categories": [],
    "menu_items": [],
    "menu_modifier_groups": [],
    "menu_modifier_items": []
  }
]
```

How can I use `ng-repeat` to group by `menu_categories`? `menu-items` is a child of `menu_categories`

Basically I want to display `menu_items`, `menu_modifier_groups`, `menu_modifier_items` grouping them by `menu_categories`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your data model.  How do you know what menu_items are in each menu_category?

Comment: They're all related from my `DB`.. `one-to-many` relationship

Comment: Hope you have "categories id" in menu_items, menu_modifier_groups, menu_modifier_items. so refer this https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby

Comment: @Venkatraman groupBy is in core now also

Comment: yep. i shared group by option

Comment: @moh.ABK, please share the whole json response to avoid assumption

Comment: @moh.ABK, will proceed further once you replied

Comment: @Venkatraman It's too long and SO won't let me add it. `menu_category_id` is the common key for all the 3 arrays I want under `menu_category_id`

Comment: add one sample array element for each array as a example

Comment: @Venkatraman SO still giving error; all the items in the arrays have `name` and `menu_category_id`

Answer (score 0):

i think you can sort (generally manipulate) your array using a filter and then do the `ng-repeat`, and it won't necessarily change the original data. so inside the html you can do it like this: `ng-repeat="item in myArray | myFilter: otherData"`.

and defining your filter in the js file like:

```
.filter('myFilter', function () {
        return function(input, otherData) {
            var output = [];
            //some changes using "if"s and other things depending on your sorting algorithm
            return output;
        };
    })
```

if you have problem with the sorting algorithm, it would help if you could give us the real data...

hope this helps